# How do I embed a Flask-Security login form on my page?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-security

Using the example code provided by Flask-Security, I can access the `login_user.html` form from the `/login` route normally and that works just fine. However, I would like to embed the login form on all my site's pages in the upper left. I thought I could use a Jinja `{% include "security/login_user.html" %}` statement to place the form in `base.html`, but that doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'login_user_form' is undefined
```

Is there a way to include or embed the login form inside another template and still get access to the respective form object?

Answer (score 15):

`security/login_user.html` is the full page template for the login form. It's not what you would want to embed on each page because it deals with other things like flashed messages, errors, and layout.

Write your own template to render just the form and include *that*, or add it to your base template.

```html
<form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST">
  {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ login_user_form.email(placeholder='Email') }}
  {{ login_user_form.password(placeholder='Password') }}
  {{ login_user_form.remember.label }} {{ login_user_form.remember }}
  {{ login_user_form.submit }}
</form>
```

<sup>(This is just an example, you'll want to style it to fit your page.)</sup>

None of your views will deal with the login form directly, so `login_form` and `url_for_security` aren't available while rendering most templates (this was causing the original issue you observed). Inject them for each request using `app.context_processor`.

```
from flask_security import LoginForm, url_for_security

@app.context_processor
def login_context():
    return {
        'url_for_security': url_for_security,
        'login_user_form': LoginForm(),
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace reads:
`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'login_user_form' is undefined`

This error message is coming from Jinja, which is saying that `login_user_form` is undefined.

To solve this, if this was your `base.html`,

```
...
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post" name="post">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
...
```

you've to pass `login_user_form` as a context variable to your render template. So, in your `/login` route, you should return something like this:

```
return render_template("base.html",
        title = 'Home',
        form = login_user_form)
```